# Is there any way to change the x-axis scale in line-graph in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IfeZ.png) is how it looks right now. It is hours of a day so I want it to be either every alternate hour or every hour. Having a scale of 5 doesn't really help the visuals.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! Please read the way how the questions are asked here. The questions are expected to have all the required information within itself so question will have sense when the foreign links become invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_continuous` to set breaks along the x-axis. Here is an example using the `pressure` dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 400, by = 50),
                     limits = c(0, 400)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]